# PHP read white space in file

Tags: php, whitespace

I have a file that looks like:

```
I       int result = 2 * n;
        result = result + 1;

II      int result = n + 1;
        result = result * 2;

III     int result = (n + 1) * 2;
```

I read and write the file with:

```
while(!feof($myfile)) {
    
    $line =  fgets($myfile) ;
    echo $line . "<br>";
}
```

the output I get is:

```
I int result = 2 * n;
result = result + 1;

II int result = n + 1;
result = result * 2;

III int result = (n + 1) * 2;
```

Is there a way to keep the extra spaces in the text to keep the spacing the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML does not preserve multiple spaces, so replace them with `&nbsp;`:

```php
while(!feof($myfile)) {
    
    $line =  fgets($myfile) ;
    echo str_replace(' ', '&nbsp;', $line) . "<br>";
}
```